# What is behind this odd issue where express route doesn't work with one route name and does with another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm experiencing an odd issue where, if I write one route, it redirects to my home page, for reasons beyond me. But if I change even one letter in the route, it all works perfect.

It seems if I write exactly this, with 'entries' in the end, when going to that link, I just get redirected, no matter what the contents of the route. The following does not work (results in immediate redirect, seemingly never accesses the route at all):

```
router.get('/:username/curatas/:curataId/entries', function(req, res) {
// some code that works.
})
```

However, when I use absolutely any other choice of letters, it works! Such as omitting the 's' from 'entries' or adding and 'x', etc.

```
router.get('/:username/curatas/:curataId/entrie', function(req, res) {
// some code that works.
})
```

What could be the reason for this strange behavior? There's no error I've detected either.

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Do you get errors?

Comment: @Pointy, whenever I try access that, I get redirected to the home page. No errors. I tried to set up errors inside the route, but it seems it never even gets inside the  route. And the rest of the application continues functioning as usual.

Comment: Is it possible that that path pattern is colliding with some other path in the application?

Comment: Searched through the application looking for other paths like that, did not find any. Truly bizarre.

Comment: It seems, as @Pointy says, that this path has been defined elsewhere and makes the redirection. Are you absolutely sure that it is not duplicated considering that the parameters with ':' can be totally different (i.e. '/:whatever/curatas/:whatever/entries') ?

Comment: Do you use some middleware that might be redirecting before getting to specific route?

Comment: @VirgilioGM, checked and no such case either. And no middleware.

Comment: The redirection has to be set somewhere so you have to debug the code until you find where.

Comment: Ah! Turned out it worked on Safari! Then cleared all cache on Chrome and it works there too now. So the problem was cache, though strange, as this has not been a problem previously with any routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be cache.

I had never run into this before with any routes and didn't anticipate cache problems with backend code.

So for anyone running into a similar problem, where the current code seems to have no issues, but you're experienced odd, unexpected behavior, with no errors...

Then your problem might be cache. Try it with another browser or clear your cache.

Comment: With Chrome developer tools you can turn off caching in the network tab

Comment: @slebetman, do you have ideas for why it turned into a cache problem in this case but such a thing usually doesn't come up? Just an anomaly, or is there something specific to keep an eye out for? Also, thank you for the tip!

Comment: It was always there but you just never noticed. For non-indempotent endpoints (such as JSON generating routes that generates time-varying data) I always set `Cache-Control` header to disable cache - but this destroys performance so don't do it for everything.